# Automatic reoccurring metered billing

Tags: api, authorize.net, billing

On my marketplace I plan on charging sellers a fee to third party sellers to use my business. There is a final value fee they they will be billed based on a percentage of their sale. Every month I would like to charge their credit card stored on authorize.net based on how much each users total fees from the previous month.

Can someone direct me in the right to direction to a PHP API that allows this variable amount of reoccurring billing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [Authorize.Net Customer Information manager API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) with your own recurring billing engine.

Comment: Is there any type of dource of information I cna guide my developer towards that he can become familiar with for the billing engine?

Comment: Crontab for *nix and Scheduled Tasks on Windows will do the trick.